# Why is my encoding showing twice?

Tags: c#, sockets, utf-8, tcp

```
byte[] lengthBytes = new byte[4];
serverStream.Read(lengthBytes, 0, 4);
MessageBox.Show("'>>" + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(lengthBytes) + "<<'");
MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

This is the code I used for debugging. I get 2 messageboxes now. If I used Debug.WriteLine it was also printed twice.

```
Msgbox 1: '>>/   (Note that this is still 4 characters long, the last 3 bytes are null.
Msgbox 2: '>>{"ac<<'
Msgbox 3: Hello
```

I'm trying to send 4 bytes with an integer, the length of the message. This is going fine ('/   ' is utf8 for 47). The problem is that the first 4 bytes of the message are also being read ('{"ac'). I totally dont know how this happens, I'm already debugging this for several hours and I just can't get my head around it. One of my friends suggested to make an account on StackOverflow so here I am :p

Thanks for all the help :)

### EDIT: The real code for the people who asked

[My code http://kutj.es/2ah-j9](http://kutj.es/2ah-j9)

Comment: What does `lengthBytes` contain? And why do you try to convert them to text using an encoding?

Comment: It is empty at first, but I'm putting data into it with the NetworkStream.Read() function. I'm trying to convert it to text so I can see the result, it is more for debugging purposes as this isn't my real problem.

Comment: Does the "real" code loop around the snippet you show?

Comment: Yeah, but if I put the MessageBox.Show("Hello"); with it, that only gets showed once. The loop does this: while(true) { get 4 bytes with length; length = decode(4 bytes); get (length) bytes, the actual message. This gives an error because the first 4 bytes of the message were already read.

Comment: Provide an executable repro. Hard-code the 4 bytes that are in that array and update your post. My guess: It is not possible to reproduce this.

Comment: It is possible. It worked before. Since I implemented the JSON it broke, I don't know why.

Comment: Show the content of that `returndata` string variable please. It obviously does not contain valid JSON data...

Comment: It contains valid JSON data, but it is missing it first 4 bytes what makes the JSON invalid. Where those 4 bytes are? Who knows, that is the problem...

Comment: Sure it contains valid JSON data, that's why the JSON parser complains. Does that make any sense to you? You can either stick with your assumptions, or you can try starting to analyze your situation...

Comment: Well I'm analyzing everything for hours already. And the problem is NOT that the JSON is invalid ok? The problem is that returndata is missing it first 4 bytes and that is making the JSON invalid. We found a problem and a solution for the JSON error, add the first four bytes. That gives us the new problem, where do we get those bytes? And that is the real problem I'm questioning already the whole day.

Comment: @alk with what in it? it will only show up once because an Exception will occur (as shown in the picture) that is going to stop the while.

Comment: Okay, something does not add up in your question and screenshot (sorry i was misinterpreting your comment regarding `returndata`). How many message boxes with the angular brackets (>> and <<) do you have? According to your code in the screenshot, you read `{"ac"` in the **second** while-loop iteration (because there is only one message box with >> and <<). What about the stuff you read and output in the 3 last message boxes (Inl/Ing/In) during the **first** iteration of the while-loop?

Comment: Do you use TCP sockets with NetworkStream? It looks that way...

Comment: Yes, and there is only 1 while loop, i can guarantee you that. Note the missing <<' in the first messagebox.

Comment: If you use NetworkStream, then the following could happen. TCP has to send data in several packets if the data size exceeds roughly 1.5 KB (unless your network uses jumbo frames). Note that NetworkStream.Read(byte[], yada-yada) returns only the data received **so far**. Since your data messages most likely do not fit into a single 'normal' TCP packet it is possible that the first call of NetworkStream.Read returns only the data of the first packet(2) received (the next packets still 'being on their way'). In such a situation you will need to call NetworkStream.Read again until you got all data

Comment: Just some simple example to help you understand what perhaps might go on: Let's say you send your data like this: "1234SomeJsonData". Due to TCP protocol, this will be sent as packets containing "1234SomeJso" and "nData". You read first 4 bytes "1234", then you read the network stream again but you only get "SomeJso" -- oops. Then, you might read 4 bytes again and you get "nDat" and everything is messed up... Note that i am not sure whether your issue relates to this particular behavior of NetworkStream, but it certainly fits your problem description...

Comment: That isn't the problem, I was aware of this problem and I was going to fix it later. The problem is that the beginning of the data is missing, not the end.

Comment: Hmm... then -- just for the sake of testing/trouble-shooting -- why don't you try to reading the first, say, 16 bytes of the data the server sends and show this raw byte data here in your question. It would really be helpful to know what the raw byte data is...

Comment: "2___Hello world" Is what is being sent. The first 4 bytes are being read and telling the system that the message is 11 characters long. The system tries to get 11 characters but gets an error because it can only read 7 bytes ("o world"). So I don't know where the missing 4 bytes ("Hell") are. Because the first 4 bytes of the message (a JSON code) are missing, I'm getting a "incorrect JSON" exception.

Comment: Oh, I already tried reading the first 20 bytes and so, it was just like I expected ("2___Hello world").

Comment: No, could you please show the **raw** bytes, not some string conversion of the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58552/discussion-between-anton-and-elgonzo).

Answer (score 2):

You are making traditional programmer mistakes, everybody has to make them once to learn how to avoid it and do it right.  This primarily went off the rails by writing debugging code that is buggy and made it *lot* harder to find your mistake:

- *Never* write debugging code that uses MessageBox.Show().  It is a very, very evil function, it causes *re-entrancy*.  And expensive word that means that it only freezes the user interface, it doesn't freeze your program.  It continues to run, one of the things that can go wrong is that the code that you posted is executed again.  Re-entered.  You'll see two message boxes.  And you'll have a completely corrupted program state because your code was never written to assume it could be re-entered.  Which is why you complained that 4 bytes of data were swallowed.

The proper tool to use here is the feature that *really* freezes your program.  A debugger breakpoint.

- *Never* assume that binary data can be converted to text.  Those 4 bytes you received contain binary zeros.  There is no character for it.  Worse, it acts as a string terminator to many operating system calls, the kind used by the debugger, Debug.WriteLine() etc.  This is why you can't see the "<<"

The proper tool to use here is a debugger watch or tooltip, it lets you look into the array directly.  If you absolutely have to generate a diagnostic string then use BitConverter.GetString().

- *Never* assume that a stream's Read() method will always return the number of bytes you asked for.  Using the return value in your code is a hard requirement.  This is the real bug in your program, the only you are actually trying to fix.

The proper solution is to continue to call Read() until you counted down the number of bytes you expected to receive from the *length* you read earlier.  You'll need a MemoryStream to store the chunks of byte[]s you get.

Comment: I used Debug.WriteLine at first, but I couldn't really believe the result so i tried a MessageBox. Also, the beginning of the JSON was missing, not the end. I also don't expect it to be multiple packets because i'm only sending 51 bytes in total. I was going to do an extra while once I had this working.

Comment: Sure, Debug.WriteLine() falls victim to the second bullet, hard to believe what you see.  As indicated, get rid of the buggy debug code and only consider using the debugger instead.  Practice using it if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/744y86tc(v=vs.110).aspx) regarding Encoding.GetString() will help you out a bit. The part to pay attention to being:

> If the data to be converted is available only in sequential blocks
>   (**such as data read from a stream**) or if the amount of data is so large
>   that it needs to be divided into smaller blocks, you should use the
>   Decoder object returned by the GetDecoder method of a derived class.

Comment: Hmm if I don't use any Encoding.UTF8.GetString it is still getting 8 bytes (4 bytes too much) wich is causing an error if I want to get the rest because that is missing 4 bytes then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I started the getMessage void 2 times. This started the while 2 times (in different threads).

Elgonzo helped me finding the problem, he is a great guy :)